# Cordova app scrolls outside of view

Tags: cordova

When I try to scroll vertically in my iPhone app made with Cordova (Phonegap) and Framework7, the entire view moves instead of just the content. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tjku.jpg), instead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRioP.jpg).

The menu bar should be fixed to the top and disregard user actions. How can I change this to be correct?

Also, sorry for the lack of correct terms, I'm neither a native speaker nor as much of a technologically experienced person as the rest of you.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, got it. Adding this to config.xml helped:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```